# Source forge specific permissions

Tags: sourceforge

I recently released a project on source forge and I was wondering if there was a way to allow anyone (even anonymous users) to upload their bug fix zips to a specific folder, while the other folders still remain exclusively under my control.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third-party hosting service.

Comment: @PascalCuoq There's a tag created specially for sourceforge. 172+ questions have been asked, and It's about the final step of programming which is releasing your code. I believe It's on topic.

Comment: As of this writing, the first three after yours are also off-topic. The first two are unanswered. Existence of a tag x doesn't mean that a question about x is automatically on-topic. The tag x may have been created by mistake (it only takes one high-rep user to create a tag, and may not reflect community consensus), and some questions may be both about x and on-topic.